# jQuery .html() method seems to overwrite containing element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm writing an AJAX function that returns some information to display in a `<div>`. My code looks like this:

HTML:

`<div id="basket_summary">Your basket's empty. Why not add some items to get started?</div>`

jQuery (relevant part of ajax call):

```
success: function(products){
    $('#basket').html(products.basket);
    $('#basket_summary').html(products.summary);
```

I can confirm that the products.summary variable contains the text I want to display.

When I run this code for the first time, it works, but then when I check the source, the `<div id="basket_summary">` part is removed, so the second time I call the function, the element doesn't exist anymore. If I include `<div id="basket_summary">` in my AJAX return data, it adds it, so I end up with this:

```
<div id="basket_summary">
    <div id="basket_summary">3 items in your basket</div>
</div>
```

This isn't how the function normally works for me - it doesn't ordinarily touch the containing element. Can anybody figure this out?

Comment: Is `basket_summary` a child of `basket`?

Comment: Nope, they're in different parts of the page.

Comment: what does products.summary contain exactly? can you console.log or alert it please? It seams to me that it contains HTML code.

Comment: is your code w3c-valid ?

Comment: i can tell you its not. multiple ID's with the same name are never valid ;)

Comment: It does - `<span class="highlight">3</span> Products (&pound;209.00)` - but I've tried it with just 'hello world' and the same happens.

Comment: could you post a link? i think the error is somewhere else in your code.

Comment: can you just show the code of your page ? as per the jquery documentation .html() use innerHTML property and over write exiting content

Comment: Fixed it, you guys were right. Missed a closing <div> tag out... boy is my face red.

Comment: @Matt Andrews - Heh, we've all been there :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing that the basket_summary div is inside of the basket div, like this:

```
<div id="basket">
   <div id="basket_summary">
   </div>
</div>
```

If this is the case, when you use this line...

```
$('#basket').html(products.basket);
```

...it will erase everything inside of the basket div and replace it with whatever is in products.basket.  You might need to use [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) or [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of html().